# Has Eclipse Classic been discontinued?

Tags: eclipse

I don't see Eclipse Classic on [Eclipse Downloads](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index.php). Has it been discontinued? If so, what's the replacement if any? Eclipse SDK? Eclipse Standard? etc? (I'm trying to get Eclipse 4.5 Classic, not previous versions). I plan to use Eclipse for Python development, I used to get [Eclipse Classic](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-43-m6/keplerm6) + PyDev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It is now named](https://wagenknecht.org/blog/archives/2014/09/looking-for-eclipse-standard-download.html) **Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers** as it was always tied together for Eclipse internal development (the development of Eclipse itself).

Comment: Thanks. Did Eclipse Standard use to be the same as Eclipse Classic? I thought Eclipse Standard contained many more plugins. From your link: "Even if you don’t need it for Java development I still recommend it as a better option than starting with a vanilla Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary."

Comment: Yes classic and standard are the same. They [renamed it](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408890) from Eclipse Classic to Eclipse Standard.

Comment: What a mess... I found the stupid version names (Mars, Kepler, etc.) were confusing enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it lives here:
Downloads -> Other builds -> 4.5 -> [EC](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.5-201506032000/)

Most developers prefer ready packages so they take away Classic from the front page. Common process of changing product line =)

Comment: Thanks, so Eclipse Classic is now named Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary?

Comment: No, it is named Eclipse for Eclipse Comitters as it was always tied together for the Eclipse internal development.

Comment: As lschuetze right noted Classic was re-branded a little bit but in general it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Walking.In.The.Air Thanks, so in your list Eclipse for Eclipse Comitters is Eclipse SDK, right?